# Fast VP9 still image encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, encoding, vp9

I use this command to create "myFile.webm", a VP9 video with one still image :

```bash
$ ffmpeg -i myOriginialPureAudioFile.opus -loop 1 -i myAudioFile_640x360.png -shortest -threads 4 -speed max -c:a copy myFile.webm
Input #0, ogg, from 'myOriginialPureAudioFile.opus':
  Duration: 01:53:19.80, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      TITLE           : unnamed
      ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
Input #1, png_pipe, from 'myAudioFile_640x360.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgb24(pc), 640x360 [SAR 72:72 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'myFile.webm' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (png (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x5655578268c0] v1.3.0
Output #0, webm, to 'myFile.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 640x360 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      LANGUAGE        : eng
      TITLE           : unnamed
      ENCODER         : Lavf57.83.100
frame= 4863 fps= 22 q=0.0 Lsize=     987kB time=00:03:14.48 bitrate=  41.6kbits/s speed=0.879x
```

The speed is about 0.88x, how can I make this encoding much faster ?

Comment: Why use VP9? x264?

Comment: @Gyan Because, I don't want to re-encode the 2hours audio which in opus format. I use `-c:a copy` because the WebM container supports opus audio

Comment: So does MP4 with `-strict -2` added.

Comment: @Gyan I don't think YouTube is going to accept an MP4 file with opus audio

Comment: Try a very short file.

Comment: @Gyan It works, thanks. But I think I'll stick to standard webm file.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine, *speed=0.953x* while using the **default** setting

```
c:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -y -i out_music.opus -loop 1 -i temp.png -shortest -threads 4 -speed max -c:a copy  myFile.webm

frame=  184 fps= 24 q=0.0 Lsize=     843kB time=00:00:07.32 bitrate= 943.8kbits/s speed=0.953x
```

*speed=1.73x* while using the **realtime** setting

```
c:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -y -i out_music.opus -loop 1 -i temp.png -shortest -threads 4 -speed max -c:a copy -deadline realtime myFile.webm

frame=  491 fps= 43 q=0.0 Lsize=    1809kB time=00:00:19.60 bitrate= 755.9kbits/s speed=1.73x
```

Since the input is a png file, frame per second could be lower; *speed=5.84x* while using the **fps=5** setting

```
c:\ffmpeg\ffmpeg -y -i out_music.opus -loop 1 -i temp.png -shortest -threads 4 -speed max -c:a copy -deadline realtime -vf fps=5 myFile.webm

frame=  218 fps= 29 q=0.0 Lsize=    1316kB time=00:00:43.40 bitrate= 248.3kbits/s speed=5.84x
```

Reference:https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9

Comment: Just for information. According to [ffmpeg filters documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#fps) on the `fps` filter, `-vf fps=5` would be equivalent to `-r 5` as an output option, read `man ffmpeg  | sed -n "/-r.:/,/output option/p"`

Answer (score 0):

One solution (found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/YouTube#BasicExamples)) is to use a very small `-framerate` value.